# Does an AJAX (XMLHttpRequest) request have a timeout?

Tags: ajax, timeout, xmlhttprequest

If I do an `XMLHttpRequest` request to some server and that server doesn't return anything (it just hangs), will the `XMLHttpRequest` eventually time out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
xhr.timeout = 10000;
xhr.ontimeout = function(){ alert('Timeout!')};
```

[reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc304105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

Comment: This sets a timeout. What if I don't want a timeout? Can I leave it open all day like a `long poll`?